# AngularJS ng-max with expression (with DEMO of bug)

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-model

I have an input that can be either a numeric amount or percentage. I want to restrict the max amount of the input accordingly.

Is there a way I can add an ng-max to be either 100 if its percentage or nothing if it's a numeric amount?

I have tried the following, but it's not putting the max value to 100 when the input is a percentage:

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-max="vm.isPercent ? '100' : ''">
```

Comment: Submitted as [ISSUE #16628: ng-max allows inputs to exceed max value with up button](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16628)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the `max` attribute with interpolation:

```
    <input type="number" name="num1" ng-model="vm.num" required
           min="0" max="{{vm.isPercent ? 100 : null}}" />
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="vm={isPercent:true, num:101}">
  <form name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isPercent">Is Percent<br>
    <input type="number" name="num1" ng-model="vm.num" required
           min="0" max="{{vm.isPercent ? 100 : null}}" /><br>
    Value={{vm.isPercent ? vm.num/100 : vm.num}}
  </form>
  <div ng-show="form1.$error.max" style="color: red">
     Invalid: Percentage must be less than 100
  </div>
</body>
```

---

### DEMO of bug with `ng-max`:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="vm={isPercent:true, num:101}">
  <form name="form1">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isPercent">Is Percent<br>
    <input type="number" name="num1" ng-model="vm.num" required
           min="0" ng-max="vm.isPercent ? 100 : null" /><br>
    Value={{vm.isPercent ? vm.num/100 : vm.num}}
  </form>
  <div ng-show="form1.$error.max" style="color: red">
     Invalid: Percentage must be less than 100
  </div>
</body>
```

With the `ng-max` directive, if the user enters a number less than 100 and presses the up arrow, the number will increase to 100 and continue to increase.

It does flag it as an error and prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: You can check my example [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FZRXRZKTMbLkdAhT?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Im trying both inputs to work similar, currently with the arrows you can still add more than 100 in the input with ng-max

Comment: Updated the answer to demonstate the bug with the `ng-max` directive. The ng-max directive allows percentages higher 100.

It does flag it as an error and prevents the form from being submitted. If you want the input element to stop at 100 use the `max` attribute with interpolation `{{ }}`.

Comment: Submitted as [ISSUE #16628: ng-max allows inputs to exceed max value with up button](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16628)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a expression with the isPercent.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="{{isPercent ? 100 : null}}
```

If the isPercent is true, it will use 100 as max, and if not, it will use null, so, there will not be max value.